# PIXI.Loader is not a constructor?

Tags: java, html, pixi.js

I created a javascript file consisting of only a exportable function:

```
export function addImageToCanvas(imagePath, spriteX, spriteY) {
  const loader = new PIXI.Loader();
  loader.add('image', imagePath);
  loader.load((loader, resources) => {
    createSprite(resources.image.texture, spriteX, spriteY);
  });

  function createSprite(texture, x, y) {
    const sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
    sprite.x = x;
    sprite.y = y;
    app.stage.addChild(sprite);
  }
}
```

And I am trying to use it in my game.js:

```
import { addImageToCanvas } from "./imageLoader.js";

var cloudExists = false;

app.ticker.add(gameLoop);
app.ticker.start();
function gameLoop(delta) {    
    drawCloud();
}


function drawCloud() {
    if (cloudExists == false) {
        addImageToCanvas("images/cloud.png", 200, 200);
        cloudExists = true;
    }
}
```

"app" is defined in canvas "config" file:

```
window.app = new PIXI.Application(
    {
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: (30 / 100) * window.innerHeight,
        backgroundColor: 0x77adf7
    }

);
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

function resize() {
    const newWidth = window.innerWidth;
    const newHeight = (30 / 100) * window.innerHeight; // 30% of window height
  
    app.renderer.resize(newWidth, newHeight); 
}
window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
```

I am trying to create an image load function, but it will give me the error "Uncaught TypeError: PIXI.Loader is not a constructor".

I had this with PIXI.Application, but once I switched to this pixi.js [https://pixijs.download/release/pixi.js](Pixi.js from the tutorial) , I got it fixed but now I am having a problem with PIXI.Loader.

The function is partially made by ChatGPT, but as PIXI.Loader is mentioned in the pixi.js file it shouldnt have this error.

If this information is not enough then I can give more.

Comment: Are you sure you are using it the correct way? Their API documentation doesn't have any mention of any Loader, the only one there is from the Assets component which is now deprecated. https://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Assets.html#loader PS i am no js specialist... I just looked at their documentation

Comment: Searching a bit more, it seems your code is using an older version API of their library so I would suggest first checking whether this is the case

Comment: @JorgeCampos This is what I used: https://pixijs.download/v6.1.1/docs/PIXI.Loader.html I tried CTRL + F to search for deprec or keywords the same, but it seems like the github has been updated last on 2019. What should I to create a function that lets me freely choose the name, path, x and y for an image?

Comment: I found it, https://pixijs.com/tutorial#2 An extremely easy way to add an image.

Comment: Great!! Add an answer for your question then :) it might help others in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow will offer you the code that I had (if you ask it to make it a function), do not use that as PIXI.Loader has been deprecated.

A simple snippet will work:

```
const Image = PIXI.Sprite.from("images/image.png")
app.stage.addChild(Image);
```